Convert drawing images to simplified output with consistent stroke width
The original images are human-drawn sketches with irregular shapes and thick strokes. An example is shown below:

The goal is to extract the underlying stroke information from these images, producing a simplified output with consistent stroke width (e.g., 2 pixels) while preserving the original drawing's shape. the output is like the example below (this is just a manual drawing, not real output from code so it's not so accurate).

If I run the code to extract edge and get contour:
img = mpimg.imread('org1.jpg')    
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.Canny(img, 50, 150)
kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=2)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, ksize=5)
binary_image = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.uint8)
binary_image[img > 127] = 255
binary_image = 255 - img
img = binary_image
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')

The result below is not what I expect:

How to resolve this issue?

Maybe some kind of medial axis from scikit-image followed by potrace https://potrace.sourceforge.net/
